# How to organize your C++ code so that header files (almost) never include other header files?

Tags: c++

I recently read an article that talks about the benefits of almost never including header files inside header files. The point is to lower dependencies and compilation time. You can read it here:
https://ourmachinery.com/post/physical-design/

However I'm not sure in practice how to follow that rule. What if my header file needs to use `std::string` for the declaration of a function that I'm creating as part of my API?

Comment: That seems incredibly impractical in C++, considering templates exist and are widely used. Edit : If you can reduce the number of includes in a header, go ahead, but I would never try to eliminate *all* includes.

Comment: They are probably saying use "forward declarations" heavily, and move implemenations into the cpp files. They are not saying to "never" include other headers as surely you need some types in your interface, c++ standard containers or otherwise.

Comment: @CoryKramer The article literally says never to include headers in other headers, except 2 specific standard headers : *"Header files (.h) cannot include other header files (except for <inttypes.h> and <stdbool.h>)"* It targets C, not C++.

Comment: [Modules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) take care of these problems.

Comment: The article says *"Our solution to this is simple — we don’t use classes."* which is to me a completely ridiculous concept. At that point, you should probably not be using C++.

Comment: did you read the whole article? It explains how they achieve it

Comment: Honestly, that is the most outrageous article I've ever read (or at least skimmed). It's clearly written by a C programmer that likes writing unreadable code which compiles very fast.

Comment: imho the answer is simple: don't follow that rule ;).

Comment: You also shouldn't be using `<inttypes.h>` or `<stdbool.h>` in C++, so they clearly are writing C.

Comment: i mean there is a grain of thruth in it. Decoupling parts of your software is a honorable aim, but I think they have taken it a bit too far. Actually so far that they are not actually using C++

Comment: I use forward declarations and PIMPL both to reduce the compile time by reducing the number of headers each header includes. And I say reduce but not eliminate. This becomes important when you have 100s of source files and your projects still take many minutes to build on a 24 threaded HT CPU.

Answer (score 3):

> However I'm not sure in practice how to follow that rule.

Don't follow that "rule" for C++. They even say

> ... we don’t use classes. Our header files are written in plain old C, C99 to be precise

By all means avoid redundant includes, but don't avoid *all* includes. Certainly don't avoid all includes apart from `<inttypes.h>` and `<stdbool.h>` in C++, as those are specifically C headers (ie, you shouldn't use them in C++ at all).

> What if my header file needs to use `std::string` for the declaration of a function

If you need it, you need it. You can't easily forward-declare it as `std::string` is a typedef for `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`.

You could consider using `std::string_view` for your interface, as it's a lighter-weight type and `<string_view>` is probably smaller.

> ... creating as part of my API?

If you want to expose a genuinely minimal API, then limiting it to C might sometimes be reasonable. In that case you're pretty much limited to `const char *` for strings.

If you actually want a C++ library with a C++ interface (ie, you don't want to essentially serialize everything through C primitives), ignore this article and write C++. You can still try to avoid *unnecessary* includes, and you can still forward-declare classes that *are* amenable to it.